# How to add Points(cities) on google map path between source and destination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having two textbox **source** and **destination** with **google auto complete feature** in which user will define his/her travelling path and i will show that **path on google map with drawing line between source and destination.**

> I am dynamically generating 5 textbox in which i am binding google
>   auto complete feature to this dynamically generated textbox in which user would be able to define 5 points
>   that is cities between source and destination and i would like to show
>   all this 5 points on those line of my source and destination.

In this dynamically generating process user can remove textbox too from any position and i would like to remove those points from my google map path from source to destination.

Now my Source and destination is say suppose like this:

**Source**:Mumbai

**Destination**:Ahmedabad

**My First Dynamic Texbox Input**:Nashik

Then this nashik is not coming on the path between mumbai and ahmedabad that is not on the line of my source and destination that is i want **nashik** on **those blue line** of my **Mumbai** and **ahmedabad**

Source Code:**Not running in this fiddle** so check this plunker running perfectly:[Running demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pCVhdAIYTb8baw38C6vH?p=preview)

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('source'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = places.getPlace();
  });
  var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place1 = places1.getPlace();
  });
});

var location1;
var location2;

var address1;
var address2;

var latlng;
var geocoder;
var map;

var line;

var infowindow1;
var infowindow2;

var distance;

// finds the coordinates for the two locations and calls the showMap() function
function initialize() {
  //   $("#googlemapview").show();
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // creating a new geocode object

  // getting the two address values
  address1 = document.getElementById("source").value;
  address2 = document.getElementById("destination").value;

  // finding out the coordinates
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address1
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //location of first address (latitude + longitude)
        location1 = results[0].geometry.location;
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address2
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //location of second address (latitude + longitude)
        location2 = results[0].geometry.location;
        // calling the showMap() function to create and show the map
        showMap();
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

// creates and shows the map
function showMap() {
  // center of the map (compute the mean value between the two locations)
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((location1.lat() + location2.lat()) / 2, (location1.lng() + location2.lng()) / 2);

  // get the map type value from the hidden field
  var maptype = document.getElementById("maptype").value;

  var typeId;

  if (maptype == "roadmap")
    typeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
  else if (maptype == "hybrid")
    typeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
  else if (maptype == "satellite")
    typeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
  else if (maptype == "terrain")
    typeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;

  // set map options
  // set zoom level
  // set center
  // map type
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: typeId
  };

  // create a new map object
  // set the div id where it will be shown
  // set the map options
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // event listener to update the map type
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function() {
    maptype = map.getMapTypeId();
    document.getElementById('maptype').value = maptype;
  });


  // create the markers for the two locations
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: location1,
    title: "First location",
    draggable: true
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: location2,
    title: "Second location",
    draggable: true
  });

  // create the text to be shown in the infowindows
  var text1 = '<div id="content">' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading">First location</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>Coordinates: ' + location1 + '</p>' +
    '<p>Address: ' + address1 + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var text2 = '<div id="content">' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading">Second location</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>Coordinates: ' + location2 + '</p>' +
    '<p>Address: ' + address2 + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  // create info boxes for the two markers
  infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: text1
  });
  infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: text2
  });

  // add action events so the info windows will be shown when the marker is clicked
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
  });

  // add action events for dragging the markers
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function() {
    location1 = marker1.getPosition();
    drawRoutes(location1, location2);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'dragend', function() {
    location2 = marker2.getPosition();
    drawRoutes(location1, location2);
  });

  // initialize directions service
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  drawRoutes(location1, location2);
}

function drawRoutes(location1, location2) {
  // show new addresses

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // creating a new geocode object

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': location1
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          address1 = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': location2
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          address2 = results[0].formatted_address;
          continueShowRoute(location1, location2);
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

function continueShowRoute(location1, location2) {
  // hide last line
  if (line) {
    line.setMap(null);
  }

  // show a line between the two points
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: [location1, location2],
    strokeWeight: 7,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeColor: "#FFAA00"
  });

  // find and show route between the points
  var request = {
    origin: location1,
    destination: location2,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      alert('error: ' + status);
    }
  });

  // update text in infowindows
  var text1 = '<div id="content">' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading">First location</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>Coordinates: ' + location1 + '</p>' +
    '<p>Address: ' + address1 + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var text2 = '<div id="content">' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading">Second location</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>Coordinates: ' + location2 + '</p>' +
    '<p>Address: ' + address2 + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  infowindow1.setContent(text1);
  infowindow2.setContent(text2);
}

        var cnt = 1;
        var autocomplete = [];
        var markerPostion = [];
        var map = null;
        var marker = [];
        var usedIds = [];
        var geocoder;
        var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;
        var autocompleteOptions = {
            componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
        };

        function findAvailableId() {
            var i = 1;
            while (usedIds[i]) i++;
            usedIds[i] = true;
            return i;
        };

        function removeId(idToRemove) {
            usedIds[idToRemove] = false;
        };

        function GenerateSourceDestinationPoint() {
            if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
                var id = findAvailableId();
                var OrderingField = $("<div class='OrderingField' id='OrderingField" + id + "'/>");
                var LeftFloat = $("<div class='LeftFloat' id='LeftFloat" + id + "'/>");
                var RightFloatCommands = $("<div class='RightFloat Commands' id='RightFloat Commands" + id + "'/>");
                var upButton = $("<button id='navigate' value='up'>Up</button>");
                var downButton = $("<button id='navigate' value='down'>Down</button>");
                var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + id + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + id + "'/>");
                var removeButton = $("<img class='remove' src='../remove.png' />");
                LeftFloat.append(fName);
                LeftFloat.append(removeButton);
                RightFloatCommands.append(upButton);
                RightFloatCommands.append(downButton);
                OrderingField.append(LeftFloat);
                OrderingField.append(RightFloatCommands);
                $("#FieldContainer").append(OrderingField);
                var newInput = [];
                var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + id);
                newInput.push(newEl);
                setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0);
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
            else
                alert("Cant create more than 5 points")
        }

        $(document).on('click', "img.remove", function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000, function () {
                if (cnt > maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed)
                    cnt = cnt - 2;
                else if (cnt == 1)
                    cnt = 1;
                else
                    cnt = cnt - 1;
                var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(13);
                removeId(id);
                $(this).remove();

            });
        });

        function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i) {
            autocomplete.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions));
            var idx = autocomplete.length - 1;
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[idx], 'place_changed', function () {
                if (marker[idx] && marker[idx].setMap) {
                    marker[idx].setMap(null);
                    marker[idx] = null;
                }
                marker[idx] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + '|FF776B|000000'

                });
                marker[idx].setVisible(false);
                var place = autocomplete[idx].getPlace();
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    return;
                }
                marker[idx].setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                marker[idx].setVisible(true);
            });
        }
```

```css
html,

        body,

        #map_canvas {

          height: 100% !important;

          margin: 0 !important;

          padding: 0 !important;

        }

        #panel {

          position: absolute;

          top: 5px;

          left: 50%;

          margin-left: -180px;

          z-index: 5;

          background-color: #fff;

          padding: 5px;

          border: 1px solid #999;

        }

        /*
        Provide the following styles for both ID and class,
        where ID represents an actual existing "panel" with
        JS bound to its name, and the class is just non-map
        content that may already have a different ID with
        JS bound to its name.
        */

        #panel,

        .panel {

          font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';

          line-height: 30px;

          padding-left: 10px;

        }

        #panel select,

        #panel input,

        .panel select,

        .panel input {

          font-size: 15px;

        }

        #panel select,

        .panel select {

          width: 100%;

        }

        #panel i,

        .panel i {

          font-size: 12px;

        }

        ul.messages_layout li.left {

          padding-left: 7px !important;

        }

        .gmnoprint img {

          max-width: none;

        }

        .LeftFloat {

          float: left;

        }

        .RightFloat {

          float: right;

        }

        .FieldContainer {

          border: 1px solid black;

          width: 400px;

          height: 300px;

          overflow-y: auto;

          font-family: tahoma;

        }

        .OrderingField {

          margin: 3px;

          border: 1px dashed #0da3fd;

          background-color: #e8efff;

          height: 50px;

        }

        .OrderingField div.Commands {

          width: 60px;

        }

        /*button {
            width: 60px;
        }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<input id="maptype" type="hidden" value="roadmap" />
<input type="button" onclick="initialize()" value="View on Google Map" />

<br />
<br />
<label>Source</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="source" id="source">
<br />
<br />
<label>Destination</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="destination" id="destination">
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="GenerateSourceDestinationPoint()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add Points</button>
<div style="border: 1px solid -moz-nativehyperlinktext;"></div>
<div id="FieldContainer">
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```